# Where to put a cfquery in a Coldfusion Form

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery

I have a `cfquery` that is using some of FORM fields in the `WHERE` clause. My first problem is that every time I access my webpage the cfquery code appears on the top of the page.  Where should I put the query within the .cfm form and access some of the fields within the form?  My second problem is I'm not sure that the `WHERE` clause is recognizing the values for the fields.  Can you help me please?

Here is the way my code is set up:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function addRow() { 
     var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
     var lastRow = tbl.rows.length; 
     var iteration = lastRow - 3;
     var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);
     ........... etcetra.......
}
</script>
</head>
<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>
<div class=Section1>
<cfparam name="awardTotals" default="0" />
<cfparam name="search_award.GrandTotal" default="0" />
<cfif isDefined("form.Finalize")>
   <cfquery name="search_award" datasource="Test">
    SELECT g.Code1 + g.Code2 + g.Code3 + g.Code4 AS GrandTotal
      FROM Codes g 
     WHERE g.CodeNumber = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.CodeNum#">
       AND g.TestYear = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.TestYear#">
       AND g.SelType = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.SelType#"> 
       AND g.Jurisdiction = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.SelJuris#">    
   </cfquery>
   <cfif not search_award.GrandTotal is FundingTotals>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         alert('The totals do not match.');
   return false;       
</script>
   <cfelse>
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert('The totals match.');
   return true;
</script>      
    </cfif>
</cfif>
<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><
<cfoutput>
  <form name="thisform" action="FormData.cfm" method="post">
    <p class=MsoNormal align=left style='text-align:left'>
      <input type="hidden" id="totalFields" name="totalFields" value="0">
      <input type="text" id="awardTotals" name="#search_award.GrantTotal#" value="0">
      <table width="1177" border="1" id="tblSample">
          <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes'>
          <th height="10"bgcolor="##cccccc" colspan="10"><h3>Jurisdiction:
             <select name="SelJuris" id="SelJuris">
                <option value = "0">---Jurisdictions---</option>
                <option value = "1">Allegany County</option>
                <option value = "2">Anne Arundel County</option>
                <option value = "3">Baltimore County</option>
                <option value = "4">Calvert County</option>
                <option value = "5">Caroline County</option>
             </select>
             <input name="CodeNum" id="CodeNum" type="text" size="20">  
             <input name="TestYear" id="TestYear" type="text" size="20"> 
             <input name="SelType" id="SelType" type="text" size="20">  
          </th>
          </tr>
</table>
<input type="Submit" name="Submit Form" value="Submit Form" onClick="">
<input type="Button" name="Finalize" value="Finalize" onClick="">
</form>
</body>
</cfoutput>
</html>
```

**(Update from comments)**

Right now I'm getting a message that `Element CODENUM is undefined in FORM`

Comment: Is your coldfusion code displaying or are you getting an error because it's trying to execute?

Comment: Well right now I'm getting a message that my  Element CODENUM is undefined in FORM.

Comment: Not related to your immediate question, but just in general, can I make these observation: 1) mishmashing DB/business logic in with display logic is not a great approach to writing code. Can I recommend you read up on MVC; 2) never hard code values from the user into your SQL string. Never. Use CFQUERYPARAM tags.

Comment: @AdamCameron I just started in CF and the MVC separation rules haven't dawned on me yet while using it. CF is so streamlined in how it interacts with the DB that it makes it very easy to violate them. I suppose one way a controller could be implemented is by functions defined in a command file (cfc). Very good point indeed!

Comment: @SamusArin CFML ease of use and how it's documented kinda encourage substandard practice, unfortunately. If you need to bounce ideas of other CFMLers, make sure to join the CFML Slack channel: http://cfml-slack.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @AdamCameron Invaluable and cool resource, appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

You want this sort of logic.  If the form has been submitted, do something with it.  In your case, it would be like this:

```
<cfif structkeyexists(form, "codenum")>
 query, process, display, etc
<cfif>
rest of page
```

Also, you want to use query parameters for a variety of reasons.  So this:

```
g.CodeNumber = '#form.CodeNum#'
```

becomes this:

```
g.CodeNumber = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.CodeNum#">
```

unless it's a number in which case you change the datatype.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: Element GRANDTOTAL is undefined in SEARCH_AWARD.                                                       The error is on this line of code:  <input type="text" id="awardTotals" name="awardTotals" value="#search_award.GrandTotal#">

Comment: @tnbumbray - The query only runs when the form is submitted. So you need to verify it exists before accessing it ie `structKeyExists(variables, "yourQueryName")>` or set a default value, so it always exists. That said, the flow of your form does seem right. You are using `form` fields to run a query, then using the query to populate the `form` fields..? Seems circular...

Comment: You've got a bit of chicken and the egg scenario happening here. Your query can't simultaneously require data from the same form and also populate the grand total data in the form. You might have to break this up into 2 steps or set a default value for search_award.grandtotal using CFPARAM to avoid this.

Comment: Actually I want to use the form fields to find the GrandTotal and then compare the GrandTotal with another field.  If the totals match I will continue.

Comment: Okay, I added the CFPARAM but, it's still not working.  I don't think it's recognizing the query.  Is there a way I can call the query in the "onclick".

Comment: *it's still not working* Because your variable names do not match! *Is there a way I can call the query in the "onclick"* No. Javascript knows nothing about CF. Javascript executes in the browser **after** all the server side code (ie CFML) has executed. What you can do is use ajax to submit a new http request to the server. Invoke a page that runs a query and returns some response.

Comment: And you might want to mark @Dan's answer as correct since he did correctly answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need add a condition around your cfquery. Also update the name of your submit button without spaces

```
<input type="Submit" name="SubmitForm" value="Submit Form" onClick="">



   <cfif isDefined("form.SubmitForm")>

          <cfquery name="search_award" datasource="TrenaTest">
               SELECT g.Code1 + g.Code2 + g.Code3 + g.Code4 AS GrandTotal
                FROM Codes g 
              WHERE g.CodeNumber = '#form.CodeNum#'
              AND g.TestYear = '#form.TestYear#'
              AND g.SelType =  '#form.SelType#'
              AND g.JurisdictionID = '#form.SelJuris#'  
         </cfquery>

    </cfif>
```

Comment: I tried the code this way but, I don't think my code recognizes the when I click the button.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that in all the examples, a standard html form tag is being used, but the condition for the query is defined in the Coldfusion form scope. I believe you would need to convert the `<form>` to `<cfform>` and `<input>` to `<cfinput>` like:

```
      ...........
<cfinput type="Submit" name="SubmitForm" value="Submit Form" onClick="">
</cfform>
<cfif isdefined('form.submit')>
      .............
```

Comment: Sorry @bphillips, the ColdFusion form scope works with both form and cfform tags.  All cfform really does is enable some client-side validation

Comment: Thx... I agree that it is just a wrapper for HTML controls. I was inacurate.